# Query all years, but only once

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the columns id, start, status. Start is the time when a user got a certain status, and it's saved as a unix timestamp.

This table has several thousand of hits and the same year will show up in the start column many times, but i only want the year once.

I want it to look like this

```
year status14Count Status15Count
2013  8235          23423
2014  394          2187
2015  111          111
```

And not like this

```
year status14Count Status15Count
2013  8235          23423
2013  8235          23423 
2014  394          2187
2015  111          111
```

I have tried to select with a "LIMIT" and BETWEEN, is this possible to do? 
Any tips and pointers would be helpful!

Comment: will the other values be the same? If not - what should happen to them if you just wanna show one result per year?

Comment: what does your query look like - presume you have a group statement there

Comment: Sounds like any solution would be slow. Assuming the past doesn't change, you should be able to set up and manage a separate table just for reporting. This way reports will be much much faster.

Comment: Otherwise a `SELECT DISTINCT` would probably be the easier way to alter your query to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is guesswork: you didn't show us your query. I can't tell where you get `status14Count` and `status15Count`.  But this kind of thing should work. You need aggregate functions and GROUP BY.

```
SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) year,
        SUM(status=14) status14Count,
        SUM(status=15) status15Count
   FROM TABLE
  GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) 
  ORDER BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
```

This works because expressions like `status=14` have the value 1 when true, 0 when false, and NULL when `status` is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, wouldn't `GROUP BY` work?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `year`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a conditional count.

```
SELECT 
 FROM_UNIXTIME(`start`, '%Y') AS `year`, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN `status` = 14 THEN 1 END) AS status14Count,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN `status` = 15 THEN 1 END) AS status15Count
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY `year`
ORDER BY `year`;
```